# Поиск по символу и инвертирование всех слов на этот символ

Tags: ассемблер

Попытался соединить готовый код со своим. Однако поиск по символу в стеке игнорируется. В чём проблема и как лучше исправить?

```
dseg segment
        str_max db 80
        str_len db 0
        string db 81 dup (?)  
        symbol db 0 
        str_ent db 13,10, '$'

dseg ends

sseg segment stack
db 60 dup (?)
top db ?
sseg ends
cseg segment
        assume cs:cseg, ds: dseg, ss: sseg

main:
mov ax,sseg
mov ss,ax
mov ax,dseg
mov ds,ax
mov sp,offset ss:top
mov ah,0ah
mov dx,offset str_max
int 21h
mov di,offset string
mov bl,str_len
mov bh,0
add bx,di  
dec bx   ;vi4itanie 1      
mov dx, offset str_ent
mov ah,09h
int 21h      
mov   ah,1          
int   21h             
or    al,20h          
mov   [symbol],al       
xor   bx,bx          
xor   cx,cx           
mov   cl,[str_len]   
mov   di,offset string      
mov   al,' '          
find:  repne scasb       ;do pervogo ravenstva 
       jcxz  inverse           
       mov   ah,byte[di]    
       or    ah,20h          
       cmp   ah,[symbol]   
       jne   miss            
       inc   bl             
miss:  
jmp   find  
inverse:
cmp di,bx
jnb word
mov al,[di]
mov ah,[bx]
mov [di],ah
mov [bx],al
inc di
dec bx
jmp inverse

word:
mov di,offset string
mov cl,str_len
mov ch,0
add cx,di
dec cx

next:
mov bx,di

cycle1:
cmp bx,20h
je inverse
cmp bx,cx
jnb last
inc bx
jmp cycle1

inword:
mov si,[bx+1]

cycle2:
cmp di,bx
jnb end
mov al,[di]
mov ah,[bx]
mov [di],ah
mov [bx],al
inc di
dec bx
jmp cycle2

end:
mov di,si
jmp next

last:
cmp di,bx
jnb print
mov al,[di]
mov ah,[bx]
mov [di],ah
mov [bx],al
inc di
dec bx
jmp last

print:
mov dx, offset str_ent
mov ah,09h
int 21h
mov di,offset string
mov cl,str_len
mov ah,02h

cycle3:
mov dl,[di]
int 21h
inc di
dec cl
jnz cycle3
mov ah,10h
int 16h
int 20h
mov ah,4ch
int 21h
cseg ends
end main
```

Comment: По символу в стеке? Что конкретно должен делать код?!

Comment: Нужно:
1) Ввести строку
2) Ввести букву
3) Найти все слова на указанную букву и записать их наоборот.
4) Вывести строку с преобразованием выше.